# (Dirichlet) Boundary conditions in harmonic oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

Consider $$y'' + y = 0, \forall x \in (0,\pi)$$
with boundary conditions $y(0)=y(\pi) = 0$ 
The general solution is :

$$y(x) = a\cos(x) + b\sin(x), \forall x \in (0,\pi)$$

This equation (in a more general form at least) can be found in the process of trying to solve a pde by separation of variables(e.g. heat equation). **My question** is: given that the region where the ODE holds is the **open** interval $(0,\pi)$ why is it "legal" to apply the boundary conditions in the general solution?